# Why absolute positioning does not work in this case _ its top and Left values

Tags: absolute

I have done some absolute positioning with css. But in the following case, why in the **firstBox** , the **top** and **left** values are ignored? (I want top at 100 px and left at 100px). The Second box is pisitioned correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<style type="text/css">
#firstBox {
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: red;
  position::absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
 z-index:2;
}
#secondBox {
    color: white;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="firstBox"> The First Box! </div>
<div id="secondBox"> The Second Box! </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using **2 colons** for `position: absolute;` for `#firstBox`

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5u5Z9/)

Comment: `;` is a semi-colon; `:` is a colon. He's got two colons, not semi-colons. Two semi-colons probably wouldn't mess it up, since the first one would close the `position` property and it would be valid. It'd be followed by an empty property, which is invalid, but most browsers should ignore than and correctly use the valid properties around it.